# ARKit – Adding bounding box to anchor?

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit, arview

I'm using: ARView, RealityFoundation

I am using the following source code to add boxes to ARView [image]
But now it will draw boxes (mesh), my goal just want to draw bounding boxes (depicted in the following image)
[image]

I think to change ModelComponent(mesh: mesh, materials: [material]) => another data type, but I can't do it yet.

any of your answers are appreciated by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the apple documentation regarding "Scanning and Detecting 3D Objects".

Link: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects)

You can also follow this writing to have more detailed idea:

[Bounding box to anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552293/show-bounding-box-while-detecting-object-using-arkit-2)

Comment: Most welcome. Up it if that helps :)